# How to not indent the section title

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I have a document with `article` class. And the header for section and subsection is indented. I would like to make it so that the header lines up with paragraph that is not indented.

For example

Right now it is

> **Abstract**
>
> Start of paragraph....
>   second line of paragraph

I would like it to look like this:

> **Abstract**
>
> Start of paragraph...
>   second line of paragraph

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: By default, section titles and the abstract title are not indented. (It might be centred or it might be flush left but it won't be indented.) So I suspect that you are not using semantic markup but, rather, marking up the format manually. But it is impossible to say without seeing the code. Hence, we need an MWE.

Comment: Don't write `\textbf{Abstract}`. Instead use `\section*{Abstract}`. Without more detail, it's difficult to say what you're currently using and what the use-case is.

Comment: And if `\section*{Abstract}` is too big, there's always `\subsection*{Abstract}`. Some document classes even let you simply type `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}`.

Comment: @JohnWickerson 'Some classes' includes `article`... `\begin{abstract}...\end{abstract}` is what I would use. But `\section*{Abstract}` might be better if a flush left result is wanted.